# How does kernel restrict processes to their own memory pool?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, kernel

This is purely academical question not related to any OS

We have x86 CPU and operating memory, this memory resembles some memory pool, that consist of addressable memory units that can be read or written to, using their address by `MOV` instruction of CPU (we can move memory from / to this memory pool).

Given that our program is the kernel, we have a full access to whole this memory pool. However if our program is not running directly on hardware, the kernel creates some "virtual" memory pool which lies somewhere inside the physical memory pool, our process consider it just as the physical memory pool and can write to it, read from it, or change its size usually by calling something like `sbrk` or `brk` (on Linux).

My question is, how is this virtual pool implemented? I know I can read whole linux source code and maybe one year I find it, but I can also ask here :)

I suppose that one of these 3 potential solutions is being used:

- Interpret the instructions of program (very ineffective and unlikely): the kernel would just read the byte code of program and interpret each instruction individually, eg. if it saw a request to access memory the process isn't allowed to access it wouldn't let it.
- Create some OS level API that would need to be used in order to read / write to memory and disallow access to raw memory, which is probably just as ineffective.
- Hardware feature (probably best, but have no idea how that works): the kernel would say "dear CPU, now I will send you instructions from some unprivileged process, please restrict your instructions to memory area `0x00ABC023 - 0xDEADBEEF`" the CPU wouldn't let the user process do anything wrong with the memory, except for that range approved by kernel.

The reason why am I asking, is to understand if there is any overhead in running program unprivileged behind the kernel (let's not consider overhead caused by multithreading implemented by kernel itself) or while running program natively on CPU (with no OS), as well as overhead in memory access caused by computer virtualization which probably uses similar technique.

Comment: Also see [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track when you mention a hardware feature. This is a feature known as **[protected mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)** and was introduced to x86 by Intel on the 80286 model. That evolved and changed over time, and currently x86 has 4 modes.

Processors start running in **real mode** and later a privileged software ([ring0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), your kernel for example) can switch between these modes.

The virtual addressing is implemented and enforced using the [paging mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) ([How does x86 paging work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431262/298054)) supported by the processor.

Answer (score 4):

On a normal system, memory protection is enforced at the MMU, or memory management unit, which is a hardware block that configurably maps virtual to physical addresses.  Only the kernel is allowed to directly configure it, and operations which are illegal or go to unmapped pages raise exceptions to the kernel, which can then discipline the offending process or fetch the missing page from disk as appropriate.

A virtual machine typically uses CPU hardware features to trap and emulate privileged operations or those which would too literally interact with hardware state, while allowing ordinary operations to run directly and thus with moderate overall speed penalty.  If those are unavailable, the whole thing must be emulated, which is indeed slow.

Comment: Or maybe not too broad :) Are you aware of any OS with memory protection without hardware support?