# Kernel memory management: where do I begin?

Tags: memory, memory-management, kernel, paging, virtual-memory

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to kernel programming, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for beginning the implementation of memory management in a kernel setting. I am currently working on a toy kernel and am doing a lot of research on the subject but I'm a bit confused on the topic of memory management. There are so many different aspects to it like paging and virtual memory mapping. Is there a specific order that I should implement things or any do's and dont's? **I'm not looking for any code or anything, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.** Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn paging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work and see some minimal examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d1f11492c2d2828c9c713d75b6f173da955aafc3/paging.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple aspects that you should consider separately:

- Managing the available physical memory.
- Managing the memory required by the kernel and it's data structures.
- Managing the virtual memory (space) of every process.
- Managing the memory required by any process, i.e. `malloc` and `free`.

To be able to manage any of the other memory demands you need to know actually how much physical memory you have available and what parts of it are available to your use.
Assuming your kernel is loaded by a multiboot compatible boot loader you'll find this information in the [multiboot header](http://wiki.osdev.org/Multiboot) that you get passed (in `eax` on x86 if I remember correctly) from the boot loader.
The header contains a structure describing which memory areas are used and which are free to use.

You also need to store this information somehow, and keep track of what memory is allocated and freed. An easy method to do so is to maintain a bitmap, where bit `N` indicates whether the (fixed size `S`) memory area from `N * S` to `(N + 1) * S - 1` is used or free. Of course you probably want to use more sophisticated methods like multilevel bitmaps or free lists as your kernel advances, but a simple bitmap as above can get you started.

This memory manager usually only provides "large" sized memory chunks, usually multiples of `4KB`. This is of course of no use for dynamic memory allocation in style of `malloc` and `free` that you're used to from applications programming.

Since dynamic memory allocation will greatly ease implementing advanced features of your kernel (multitasking, inter process communication, ...) you usually write a memory manager especially for the kernel. It provides means for allocation (`kalloc`) and deallocation (`kfree`) of arbitrary sized memory chunks. This memory is from pool(s) that are allocated using the physical memory manager from above.

All of the above is happening inside the kernel. You probably also want to provide applications means to do dynamic memory allocation. Implementing this is very similar in concept to the management of physical memory as done above:

A process only sees its own virtual address space. Some parts of it are unusable for the process (for example the area where the kernel memory is mapped into), but most of it will be "free to use" (that is, no actually physical memory is associated with it). As a minimum the kernel needs to provide applications means to allocate and free single pages of its memory address space. Allocating a page results (under the hood, invisible to the application) in a call to the physical memory manager, and in a mapping from the requested page to this newly allocated memory.

Note though that many kernels provide its processes either more sophisticated access to their own address space or directly implement some of the following tasks in the kernel.

Being able to allocate and free pages (`4KB` mostly) as before doesn't help with dynamic memory management, but as before this is usually handled by some other memory manager which is using these large memory chunks as pool to provide smaller chunks to the application. A prominent example is [Doug Lea's allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html). Memory managers like these are usually implemented as library (part of the standard library most likely) that is linked to every application.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.