# How can multiple processes access the same virtual memory addresses in custom Kernel?

Tags: c, kernel, paging

I'm writing a toy kernel and am quite curious how multiple processes can access the same virtual memory addresses. What I'm trying to say is, if I map the address 0x00000000 to 0x10800000 in physical space (using paging) how can separate process have their own protected memory that starts at 0 and goes to the end of their allocated memory? do they have to have separate mappings or...? I'd just like to get some clarification on this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, each process has their own memory mappings (also having 0 as a valid page is probably not a good idea if you're using `NULL = 0x0`)

Comment: Each process has its own mapping from virtual to physical memory, so even if 2 processes access the same virtual memory address (the value of the pointer), it can be different physical memory. This is handled by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: A null pointer constant is not the same as address `0`.

Comment: @Olaf I know. But if you are using the address `0` as the null pointer constant, then it's not a good idea to have address `0` be mapped (and thus accessible).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Tell this an embedded system programmer where SRAM starts at address `0`;-). Yes, this is a nasty situation and should be avoided, if possible. But sometimes you cannot. One advantage of C is that there is no implicit check for a null pointer (allthough I sometimes wish the CPU would provide such in hardware - perhaps if they have more then 100 billion transistors per die they finally have safe instruction sets, not only security extensions which restict the users).

Comment: @Olaf Well yes, if you don't have virtual memory, then you're stuck with having `0` as a valid RAM address. But OP is asking about virtual memory, so I don't think it would be too much to ask to unmap the `NULL` address so that it isn't valid :)

Comment: I could always just map virtual memory starting somewhere besides 0, I simply gave that as an example.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: That's why I wrote "should be avoided, if possible". Alternatively one could use a different null pointer constant, or even use a bit in a pointer - both are valid in C. `~(uintptr_t)0` comes into mind. But that would likely require changing the compiler:-)

Comment: Learn paging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work

Comment: On most systems, the first page is not mapped BY DEFAULT. An application can then map the page if it desires.