# IA-32E Paging Example

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

When trying to set up virtual memory I'm a bit confused about where to go regarding mapping a given virtual address to a physical address.  When working with x86 architecture and using IA-32E mode I have a function to map a new virtual page

```
    int allocate_page(page_table_entry* p)
{
    //Get Physical Block for this page table entry to point to
    void* phys = getFreeBlock();
    //Here I need to map the virtual entry to this physical page frame

}
```

According to the [Intel Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081259/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) For a 4 level page table, the first 4 bits of the virtual address should give the Page Directory Table Pointer, the next 9 bits should give the Page Directory, the next 9 bits are used to find the Page Table, and the last 12 bits are used for the offset in the page frame, for a total of 52 bits.  Does anybody have any resources or a suggestion of how I can get started implementing the rest of this function so that I can take a given virtual address and map it to a free page frame?

Comment: Read this for the theory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work I have a minimal 32-bit example at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/5c672f73884a487414b3e21bd9e579c67cd77621/paging.S If you extend it to 64-bit, send me PR, shouldn't be too hard :-)