# Page frame number vs. Page table entry

Tags: operating-system, paging, memory-address

So what exactly are the difference between page frame number and page table entry?

which one of the following is true:

```
physical_address = PTE * page_size + offset
```

```
physical_address = PFN * page_size + offset
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work/18431262

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
physical_address = PFN * page_size + offset
```

**is correct.**

The *page frames* are contiugous `page_size`-aligned and `page_size` big chunks of memory, which fill the whole virtually addressable memory.

The *page table entries* are contained in *virtual addresses*. In turn, the entries contain *page frame numbers*, so that the `n`<sup>th</sup> entry selects the `m`<sup>th</sup> page frame. You can view it like that:

```
virtual -> physical
    PTE -> PFN
```

After all you can say that *page table entries* point to *page frames*.

Comment: so is the PFN is referencing the virtual address, and PTE is referencing the physical address?

Comment: @carrotzoe Oh, crap, **no**. Confused "virtual" and "physical."

Comment: @carrotzoe Which part specifically? What in particular don't you understand?

Comment: ohhh, wait, you edited your answer. So is it that PTE references virtual and PFN references physical?

Comment: @carrotzoe In a way. A virtual address references a PTE, which points to a PFN, which gets translated, in addition with the offset, to a physical address.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm taking an OS course rn, and am getting really confused.

Comment: Hi! Wouldn't all page frame numbers just be next to each other, i.e. wouldn't the difference between two consecutive PFNs in a page table be 1 for the same process?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there are no PAGES in physical memory. A logical memory PAGE is mapped to a physical memory PAGE FRAME by a page table entry.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment? And just out of interest, which line is this referring to?

Comment: Q: "So what exactly are the difference between page frame number and page table entry?"
A: Given above.